# How to convert RDD[CassandraRow] to DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

Currently this is how I am transforming Cassandrarow RDD to dataframe:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(15))

val dstream = new ConstantInputDStream(ssc, ssc.cassandraTable("db", "table").select("createdon"))

import sqlContext.implicits._

dstream.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
    val dataframeJobs = rdd.map(w => (w.dataAsString)).map(_.split(":")).map(x =>(x(1))).map(_.split(" ")).map(x =>(x(1))).toDF("ondate")
}
```

As you can see, I am converting first cassandraRow rdd to string first, and then mapping to the format I want. I find this method to get complicated as when the rdd contains multiple coloumns instead of just one (createdon) as shown in the example.

Is there any other alternative and easy way to convert cassandraRow RDD to dataframe?

My build.sbt is as follows:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.0.2"
)
```

Comment: you could have done in one map instead of nested maps as `dstream.map(stream => stream.toString.split(":")(0).split(" ")(1)).toDF("ondate")`

Comment: What's your usecase? Do you want to load the cassandra table on each streaming interval? What would you do with it later on?

Comment: Ya I want to load the cassandra table on each streaming interval. I am writing spark-computed result to another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an alternative way which could work with any number of coloumns effectively:

rdd.keyBy(row => (row.getString("createdon"))).map(x => x._1).toDF("ondate")

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the scaladoc of [SparkContextFunctions](http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/ApiDocs/2.0.1/spark-cassandra-connector/#com.datastax.spark.connector.SparkContextFunctions) (removing the implicit params):

> **cassandraTable[T](keyspace: String, table: String): CassandraTableScanRDD[T]** Returns a view of a Cassandra table as CassandraRDD. This method is made available on SparkContext by importing `com.datastax.spark.connector._`
>
> Depending on the type parameter passed to cassandraTable, every row is converted to one of the following:
>
> - an CassandraRow object (default, if no type given)
> - a tuple containing column values in the same order as columns selected by CassandraRDD#select
> - object of a user defined class, populated by appropriate ColumnMapper

So, I'd recommend using the following:

```
ssc.cassandraTable[String]("db", "table").select("createdon")
```

That should give you the easiest possible way to access `createdon` per the docs.

---

I'm also wondering why you don't use DataFrame that spark-cassandra-connector supports as described in [Datasets](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#datasets-previously-dataframes). With that your code might get slightly simpler.

You could try to replace Spark Streaming (*almost* officially obsolete) with Spark SQL's [Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html):

> **Structured Streaming** is a scalable and fault-tolerant stream processing engine built on the Spark SQL engine. You can express your streaming computation the same way you would express a batch computation on static data. The Spark SQL engine will take care of running it incrementally and continuously and updating the final result as streaming data continues to arrive.

I'm not sure however if Cassandra Spark Connector supports it.